# Object representation HTML

Tags: javascript, html, object

I want to get all elements without textNode in my new Object. I write code and is ok:

```js
var el1 = document.childNodes[0]
var x = el1;

function get(node, ob)
{ 
   ob = ob || {};
   var parentNode = node;
   var node_length = parentNode.childElementCount

   var typElem = parentNode.nodeType
   var name = parentNode.nodeName;
 
   for (var x = 0; x < node_length; x++)
   {   
      if (node_length > 0)
      {
         ob[parentNode.childNodes[x].nodeName] = {}
         get(parentNode.childNodes[x], ob[parentNode.childNodes[x].nodeName]) 
      }
      else
      {

      }
   };
   return ob
}

var o = get(el1)
console.log(o)
```

```html
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <h1 id="a">Site 3</h1>
      <script src="index.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

It shows me: `Object { HEAD: Object, BODY: Object }`

It ok but I want this representation: `HTML:{ HEAD: Object, BODY: Object }`

How to modify the function to receive such a result?

Comment: Do `console.log({HTML: o})` instead? It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you better explain which *value* you expect to get, instead of how you want something to "look" like? (because comparing "looks" of console output is inaccurate and mostly useless).

Comment: i want to get HTMLelements into object. But parent object must be first element in nodelist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursive function `get` adds the child nodes of `node` to `ob`, so it skips the root `html` element. What you would want to do is add `node` to `ob` instead, and make sure to visit all child nodes.

There are other problems with your code, though, which makes it hard to give a working example without writing the whole thing myself.

An untested example of what you would need to do is something like this:

```
// add the *current* node to the object, not the children
ob[parentNode.nodeName] = {};

for (var x = 0; x < node_length; x++) {
   // then add the children later
   get(parentNode.childNodes[x], ob[parentNode.nodeName]);
}
```